# What does John Connor grab between his two fingers when touching the T-101 in Terminator 2 Judgement Day?

Tags: the-terminator-series, terminator-2-judgment-day

After the motorcycle/truck scene, we see John Connor touching the T-101 model to grasp the fact that Arnold really is a terminator. After touching him, it seems like he grips something between is index and thumb. Is this a metal shard of sorts or is he just pushing his fingers together to register what he just touched. I am guessing the black that I saw between these fingers was just oil from his motorcycle?

Comment: He isn't grabbing anything.  He's looking at the Terminator's blood.

Comment: Another un-accept on what seems to be a perfectly good answer. Is there something that's troubling you about these?

Comment: Valorum: Everyone has a good answer, I cannot just pick one.

Comment: Except that you seem to have systematically un-accepted the answers on every single question you've asked.

Comment: You really should accept an answer as both answers provided answer your question, you should not leave a question unanswered when you have your answer

Answer (score 8):

**Blood.**

John pokes a finger into one of the bullet holes in the Terminator's shirt and into one of the Terminator's wounds and rubs the blood between his fingers.

[image: john pokes the wound]
[image: john sees the blood]

Comment: Appreciate it. Just wanted to confirm because the T-101s body is solid metal. How would one pull out a shard if nothing was broken into?

Comment: @ArvinGBorkar - well, his endoskeleton is solid metal. The outer covering is all flesh & blood, or something close enough that we can't tell the difference.

Comment: @Omegacron: Yeah, from what I can see from this "false" skin is that it is very sensitive. Just by poking at it, John Connor was able to get blood on his fingers.

Comment: Actually, he had poked his finger into one of the bullet wounds. This was right after the scene at the mall and then the bayou chase, so the T-800 had several bullet holes in him at that point. Later, after rescuing Sarah Connor, she references the bleeding bullet wounds and asks if they'll heal up.

Answer (score 6):

The [shooting script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Terminator-2-Judgement-Day.html) explicitly states that he's touching the Terminator's blood:

> **JOHN :** *No way!*
>
> **John touches Terminator's skin. Then the blood on his jacket.** His mind
>   overloads as the reality of it hits him.
>
> **JOHN :** *Holy shit... you're really real! I mean... whoah!*
>
> (stepping back)
>
> **JOHN** (Continued) *You're, uh... like a machine underneath, right... but sort of alive outside?*
>
> **TERMINATOR :** *I'm a cybernetic organism. Living tissue over a metal endoskeleton.*

And the [Frakes novelisation](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Terminator_2:_Judgment_Day_%28Frakes_novel%29) gives us a little more info;

> *“No way!” John blurted out, but he was already convinced. Still, **John
>   touched Terminator’s skin. It felt warm, but somehow ... different.
>   Then the blood on his jacket.** It looked very real. And now he let the
>   realization sink in, and his mind overloaded as the reality of it hit
>   him.*
>
> *“Holy shit ... you’re really real! I mean ... whoa!*
>
> *You’re, uh ... like a machine underneath, right ... but sort of alive
>   outside?”*
>
> *The cyborg answered as if reading a technical manual.*
>
> *“I’m a cybernetic organism. Living tissue over a metal endoskeleton.”*

Comment: Oh I see. The bullet wound. I was like "WHAT?! How could he have touched blood just by touching his face and/or chest, which had the black shirt on." I guess I did not give much thought to when the T-1000 had shot him at the mall, in the beginning. I only thought the T-1000 shot at his back, the whole time.

Answer (score -2):

John has a conversation with the terminator about him being a human, he touches his shirt and soon realizes that the terminator is bleeding. And also notices that he feels like metal.

Comment: Whilst this seems consistent with the other answers do you have any evidence yourself that you could [edit] in?